# How do I get all files (paths) of a specific commit from gitlab api?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to load the file contents from the gitlab api using a specific tag.

This can be achieved by using the blob for each file (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html).

The problem I am facing is that I do not see the way to find out what file paths are available for a given commit (a tag in my case).

I am looking for something similar to github's tree object.

**How do I get all the files and their respective paths with a given commit hash from the gitlab api to load their contents?**

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of repository files and directories in a project by calling this API:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/tree
```

[See here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html) for more information such as optional parameters.

Comment: The way I understand this only shows the latest commit? I am looking for a way to get this tree for a given commit.

Comment: There is a parameter called `ref`, you can fill it with branch name or tag or commit hash.

Comment: oh my ... I have read this page so many times and didn't see it. Thanks that is it :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try GetDiff?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-the-diff-of-a-commit

A bit slow, hence if brings the diff text itself as well, but it works.